# Remove a ` right after the <body> using CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm using Squarspace and a character ` is generated.

All i can do is using CSS to hide it but i don't know how to do, it looks like this :

```
<body>
`
</body>
```

All i want is that ` to be removed.

I already tried this :

```
body::nth-word(1) {
  display:none;
}
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: body:first-letter {font-size:0;} ? have you tried this ?

Comment: @GCyrillus This should be an answer!:) This is awesome :)

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov not too sure it is worth an answer. Would that `:first-letter` or `:first-line` really be that handy or even  working. best is to cure the problem from it comes from to my opinion . ...

Comment: @GCyrillus Posted this as an answer, but if you do this, I'll delete mine.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov be my guest ;)

Answer (score 0):

As [GCyrillus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2442099/gcyrillus) suggested

to remove single character right after `body` use

```
body:first-letter { font-size: 0; }
```

to remove several characters right after `body` use

```
body:first-line { font-size: 0; }
```